# Validating input on client and server without writing rules twice?

Tags: jquery, validation, phalcon

I am using Phalcon to develop a web app.
I am using jQuery to do all the saving of data from the front end (which post to the Phalcon controllers).

Is there a way to write my validation rules once and have these work on both the controller and the frontend jQuery?

I want to validate the entered data on the frontend through jQuery (and show the error), however I also want to validate this data in my controller before performing my CRUD operations.

Thanks

Comment: You could use some ajax reqeust to validate on the backend and storing logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I've needed a similar approach in my application and the approach used might work well for you too. Here is it:

- Keep validation logic on server side. Client side validation should never be trusted anyway...
- Once some of your HTML is loaded in the browser fire some method to find and setup any `<form>` tag to be submitted via AJAX.
- Once all your form submits are done via AJAX, make those requests always return a proper JSON response and define some conventions such as always have a `status` property (e.g 'ok', 'error', 'internalError', etc) and some optional properties like `validationErrors`, `callback`, etc.
- Use jQuery's ajax setup to intercept the `success` event of all AJAX requests. If the response contains a `validationErrors` property you can grab the form that generated the request and display the error messages there. My `validationErrors` is an object with the input name as key and the error message as value.

I didn't provided any code because you just need to get the idea here. This way my validations are done server side and the life cycle of CRUD operations are handled in a DRY way.

If you need any further explanations, let me know.